# Select range based on 3 relative references

Tags: vba, excel

I have a very large file, where I need to select the range delimited by just 3 points in order to export it;
My references are 2 column headers that are defined, and the last cell situated before the first blank in another column.
The 2 column headers, "W" and "Z", are always in row 5, but "W" can be in cell Ax and W in cell Ay, no fixed distance between Ax and Ay.

Your help is much appreciated!

Edit - triying to add more detail as I can´t add pictures:

Let´s say I´ve 2 columns I care about first:

The first one to the left, is the one that contains the header "W", and the other, is the one that contains the header "Z".

I don´t know if there are 20 or 234 columns in the middle, if that´s the case, I would need to select all of them, as they´re betweeen my limits.

If there´s more information beyond column labeled "Z", that I don´t care.
So with this, I´ve my weidht.

Now, for the height, I need to check column "YY", which is always between "W" and "Z", and go down to the last consecutive value it has - let´s call it "E" (that means that if we´ve a blank cell in that column, I don´t care anymore about the other values below).

So, my height will go from the row that contains the label, to the one that contains value "E".

Comment: Can you give more specifics? What do you mean by delimited? What is meant by the last cell situated before the first blank in another column?

Comment: I tried to add more details, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a well defined range, using a start row, start col, and end row, end col...

```
' assumes your first row also includes the header
' a = start row
' b = start col, finds the W with a match
' c = last row of data
' d = last col
a = 5 
b = application.worksheetfunction.match("W",range("5:5"),0))
d = application.worksheetfunction.match("Z",range("5:5"),0))

' c = last row of data....
' this version uses end(xldown) aka ctrl-down arrow from the YY header in row a
c = cells(a, application.worksheetfunction.match("YY",range("5:5"),0)).end(xldown).row
'' OR
'' c = application.worksheetfunction.match("YY",range("5:5"),0)) ' to get the col
'' c = application.worksheetfunction.match("E",cells(5,c).entireColumn,0)) ' to get the row in that col that matches E assuming you dont want to go all the way down
'' OR - loop
'' i = a
'' do While cells(i,application.worksheetfunction.match("YY",range("5:5"),0)) <> ""
''    i = i + 1
'' loop
'' c = i - 1
yourRange = range(cells(a,b),cells(c,d))
```

Alternatively, you can use an intersect, but the above should work as a rough start. I suggest specifying the sheet referenced. And doing checks with some error catching to ensure W, Z and YY exists, and column for W > column for YY > column for Z

Comment: Just one question, as the "c" variable does not seem to work that well; it seems that it goes down and include some blank cells in the middle. How could I avoid that?
I filled a column with "x´s" until row 10, and then removed the "x" from row 8, and when going down, it stills select until the tenth.

Comment: It depends on the state of the data. You may need to recalculate the worksheet or column. If you just deleted the value, check to see if you use ctrl-down on that column if it goes down to row 10. You can also do a loop that goes down from row 5 until it finds a blank. Added a 3rd option for c, using a do while loop index using i = a.

Comment: Nice, that´s really helpful!
I reviewed the spreadsheet and discovered that what happened is that there were some "blanks" that were spaces instead; what should I do to include the spaces as a stop signal in the loop? 
I tried finding and replacing the spaces in that column but as the column could be anywhere I think that option would fit better.